# PHP-FPM save sessions in memcached

Tags: php-fpm, php5, memcached, session

I'm trying to switch my session_handler to memcached,
I'm not sure if it worked, it does not look like it did.

```
vi /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = unix://run/memcached/memcached.sock

/etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart
```

After hitting my blog a few times, I should have a key in the memcached, shouldn't I?

```
nc -U /run/memcached/memcached.sock

giant:~# nc -U /run/memcached/memcached.sock
stats items
END
stats slabs
STAT active_slabs 0
STAT total_malloced 0
END
```

**phpinfo():**

```
session.gc_probability  0   0
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    memcache    memcache
session.save_path   unix://run/memcached/memcached.sock unix://run/memcached/memcached.sock
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

Can someone lead me to the correct configuration please?

Comment: If You do not plan to run memcached in cluster, then I suggest to store sessions in ram (tmpfs). usually `/dev/shm`

Comment: @Guntis that's a great idea too. But I don't like the session garbage collection via cronjobs in php.

Comment: @DanFromGermany: as opposed to no gc'ing at all when storing sessions in memcached. btw: there is an internal gc-mechanism, the cronjob was introduced for more security on multiuser systems, see https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=267720

Comment: @r_3 memcached does gc using TTL. I use HHVM now which deals yet differently with sessions.

Comment: i wouldn't call memcaches lru alg a garbage collector. it's more like taking out the trash only if the dustbin is completely full as compared to when it starts to smell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not work:

```
session.save_path = unix://run/memcached/memcached.sock
```

Did work:

```
session.save_path = "/run/memcached/memcached.sock"
```

Quotes added, protocol removed

Comment: for `TCP`, use following: `session.save_path='tcp://127.0.0.1:11211, tcp://192.168.1.2:11211'`

Comment: Guys, is it actually secure to do that? Memcached doesn't have any auth in front of it.

Comment: Memcached is secured through the network layer or when you deploy it via unix socket, no other server can access it.